# Problem Based on Theorem of radius, arc length and central angle

Tags: trigonometry, circles

An arc AB of a circle with radius 28 cm and center O subtends an angle AOB at the centre. If the length of arc AB is $$\frac{88}{3}$$ cm, find the length of chord AB.

I haven't solve any question of this kind so no idea.

Comment: **HINT**: Use the arc length formula (i.e. $r\theta=l$ where $\theta$ is measured in radians) to calculate the angle AOB. You should then be able to calculate the length of the chord AB.

Comment: @Musafa I got AB=28 cm but the answer is 5 cm as shown by my book.

Comment: Please show your calculations so that we can help spot where you may have made a mistake.

Comment: $$\ theta$$=l/r =(88/3)/28=1.047 radians and converting it into degree, its approximately equal to 60°… And then using cosine law  gives AB =28 cm

Comment: Your answer is therefore correct (approx $28.01$cm) and the book is incorrect

Comment: @Mufasa thankx, i was confused on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33773/discussion-between-ger-wyn-and-mufasa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radian measure $\theta$ of a central angle of a circle with radius $r$ that is subtended by an arc of length $s$ is defined to be
$$\theta = \frac{s}{r}$$
[image: arc_length]

Since you were given $s$ and $r$, you can solve for $\theta$.

You wish to find the length of chord $\overline{AB}$.

[image: chord_length]

Draw altitude $\overline{CD}$ to side $\overline{AB}$ of $\triangle ABC$, as shown in the diagram.  Since $|AC| = |BC| = r$, $\overline{AC} \cong \overline{BC}$.  $\overline{CD} \cong \overline{CD}$ by the reflexive property of congruence.  Hence, $\triangle ACD \cong \triangle BCD$ by the Hypotenuse-Leg Theorem.  Since corresponding angles of congruent triangles are congruent, $\angle ACD \cong \angle BCD$, so $\overline{CD}$ bisects $\angle ACB$.  Hence, $m\angle ACD = \frac{\theta}{2}$.  Thus, 
$$|CD| = r\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$
and 
$$|AD| = r\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$
Since corresponding sides of congruent triangles are congruent, $\overline{AD} \cong \overline{BD}$.

Since $|AB| = |AD| + |BD|$, we obtain 
$$|AB| = 2r\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint use $S=r\theta$ where $S=arc length$ and $\theta$ is central  angle in radians. After that drop a perpendicular from central abgle to chord AB then caculate AB by using trigonometric ratios.

Comment: Can it not be donee without dropping the perpendicular @ Archis